# Can I chroot to a linux environment from windows

Tags: windows, linux, chroot

I want to know if it is somehow possible to `chroot` into a Linux system from Windows,
or, is there some technique or hack to achieve that?

Comment: Using cygwin you can get a fairly good linux environment, and you don't even have to chroot.  Is there something more you need out of it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  `chroot`ing makes no sense for operating systems that follow completely different paradigms and have not understanding of each other.  You can [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into a Linux box from Windows, but that is a completely different thing from `chroot`

Comment: Can't get internet in arch linux, need to install a few packages. Figured I could use Windows instead of a live cd.

Comment: On a dual boot system you can download packages using Windows and save them in your Windows partition. After rebooting, your ArchLinux should be able to read the files from the Windows partition after you `mount` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chroot` does not magically change the running kernel or start a new one. It only changes how much of the filesystem "chrooted" programs see, but they still run inside the same kernel. Since Linux ELF executables cannot be run on Windows directly, `chroot` will not work.

You can download your packages from https://www.archlinux.org/packages/ to disk, then install them using `pacman -U`.

Comment: Excellent answer, didn't know how chroot worked. Honestly it did seem quite magical to me.

Comment: @nikhil: In even simpler terms, it just changes the meaning of "/" in file paths. If you chroot into "/mnt/otheros" and try to access "/usr/bin/pacman", it gets invisibly translated to "/mnt/otheros/usr/bin/pacman". That's all.

Answer (score 2):

`chroot` works for Linux based systems; it has no relation with Windows,
so it is not possible.
Even if by some means you could do it, it makes no sense to do such a thing, as linux has one root and windows has many partitions at root level; their filesystems don't match at all.

Comment: Windows has `chroot` in its *Services for Unix* subsystem. Implementing it for multiple-root systems is possible as well; one could, for example, chroot into a directory containing separate directories for each virtual drive, or be limited to one virtual drive. (Also, "Unix based", not "Linux based.")

Answer (score 0):

Foreign LINUX does that: https://github.com/wishstudio/flinux
Now windows 10 got better version of this flinux for Ubuntu14.04: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

To sum it up there is no magic on executables. If you implement kernel calls correctly it will run; To be sincere it is way much easier than running Windows executables on Linux because Linux has KISS,

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that chrooting from windows could be done, using virtualisation software like VirtualBox, with a linux distro installed in a virtual machine.

Comment: This is confusing, how does one `chroot` from Windows?

Comment: you mean i install a linux distro in a vm and use that to chroot into my real system. Could you give detailed instructions on doing this.